# GR gauge condition corresponding to isotropic coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, gauge

Does anybody know what kind of gauge condition I have to use in order to work in isotropic coordinates in general relativity? I ideally want a condition on a small metric perturbation (or graviton) $h_{\mu\nu}$. For example the de-Donder gauge, corresponding to harmonic coordinates, imposes the condition $\partial_\mu h_{\mu\nu}=0$. In literature I could not find a similar statement about isotropic coordinates.

Comment: Hi. Was my answer in any way useful to you?

Comment: Defenitely! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my understanding that isotropic coordinates (in the sense of the  [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_coordinates)) on a manifold exist only under the condition that your spacetime is spherically symmetric, *i.e.* it admits a Lie algebra of 3 spacelike Killing fields that correspond to rotations.

I do not know if the *admissibility* of the isotropic coordinates can be called a gauge condition. As you can see, of course, there is no reason for these coordinates to exist for a general metric.

The necessary and sufficient condition is thus:

$$ \mathcal{L}_{X}g = 0$$

for all three linearly independent vector fields $X$ in the Lie algebra of the rotation group.
Linear independence here means - for a set of vector fields {$X_{1},X_{2},X_{3}$} in the module of smooth sections, $\Gamma(T\mathcal{M})$.

You might also describe it in a more topological way.
In order to determine if the coordinates you have are isotropic, one should probably check that:

For a chosen time coordinate $t$ on your spacetime manifold $\mathcal{M}$, the constant time hypersurfaces $\Sigma$ admit a decomposition into a family of (disjoint) topological 2-spheres.

$$ \Sigma = \bigcup_{R} S_{R}.$$

Then by restricting the metric to any such 2-sphere, one should check whether the angles are represented without distortion, quoting the wiki source.

This *without distortion* condition postulates that the induced metric is **proportional** to that of a geometric 2-sphere. Simply put, the angles you could calculate on these topological 2-spheres are the same ones as you would have on a standard 2-sphere in Euclidean space, **times** a proportionality factor depending on the radial and time coordinates.

If that is the case, you could call your coordinate system *the isotropic coordinate system*.

Any spherically symmetric spacetime admits such a coordinate system, simply because the existence of Killing vector fields allow the metric to be put in  a special form.